# Javascript Regex - Get All string that has square brackets []

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string data below:

```js
var data = "somestring[a=0]what[b-c=twelve]----[def=one-2]test"
```

I need to get all strings that contain square brackets `[]`. This is the result that I want.

```js
["[a=0]", "[b-c=twelve]", "[def=one-2]"]
```

I've tried using regex `/\[(.*?)\]/`, but what I've got is an only the first array element is correct, the next elements are basically the same value but without the square brackets.

```js
data.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
// result => ["[a=0]", "a=0"]
```

What regexp should I use to achieve the result that I want? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the `g` (global) modifier to find all matches. Since the brackets are included in the match result you don't need to use a capturing group and I used negation instead to eliminate the amount of backtracking.

```
someVar.match(/\[[^\]]*]/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In `/\[(.*?)\]/`,  `*?` means lazy, matching as few content as possible.
2. What you actually want is all the matches in content. Try modifier `g`
3. Try this one, http://regex101.com/r/aD6cM8/1. Any match starts with `[`, ends with `]`, but doesn't allow`[` or `]` inbetween.

`someVar.match(/\[([^\[\]]*)\]/g)`

Answer (score 0):

You should just add the `g` switch to your regex :

```
someVar.match(/\[(.*?)\]/); // result => ["[a=0]", "a=0"]
```

results in

```
[ "[a=0]", "[b-c=twelve]", "[def=one-2]" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is correct,  just suffix `g` to it to make it global:

`someVar.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);`

Here's more info on it: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp